# Best way to parse ASCII(?) from a hex string in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, hex, ascii

the string I get in the application includes ASCII(?) characters like !,dp,\b,(,s@.

These are suppose to be equivalent.

value in database-

```
\x01\x01\x03!\xea\x01\x00\x00dP\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\xe3\xe6\x10\x11\x98\xc3(\xc1\xa2\xc0\xa8\xc0\xa0 \x02\xc4\x0c\x1a\x8c\x1a\x0c\x1as@\x04\x18\xf2\b\x1de\xe6\xe6\xe2\xe2b604\x14`\x94\x98\xc3\ba\x9b\"\xb1M\x80\xec\xc9\x10\xb6\x81\x05\x90=\t\xca6Ab[\x02\xd9\x13\xa1\xea\x8d\x80\xec.\xa8\xb8)\x12\xdb\x0c\xc8n\x81\xaa1\x06\xb2\x1b\x19\xb98A\xe2 \xf5\xb5\x10\xa6\x01\x90Y\rf\x1a\x9a#\x98\x16\b&\xc8\x8cJ\x88Z\x90\x11\xa5\x10Q\x90\xb6\x12\x88(H[1\x84\t\xf2O\xb6\xc0&v\tF\x1e\xa1\a\x8c\xc3\xd9\x8f\x8f\x8d%\x18\x01\xa1\x98\x8d\x97\xea\x01\x00\x00
```

value I get in my app that includes chracters I don't want-

```
01010321ea010000645000001f8b0800000000000400e3e6101198c328c1a2c0a8c0a02002c40c1a8c1a0c1a73400418f2081d65e6e6e2e26236303414609498c308619b22b14d80ecc910b68105903d09ca3641625b02d913a1ea8d80ec2ea8b82912db0cc86e81aa3106b21b19b93841e220f5b510a60190590d661a9a2398160826c88c4a885a9011a5105190b6128828485b318409f24fb6c0267609461ea1078cc3d98f8f8d251801a1988d97ea0100000a\n\n"3a1ea8d80ec2ea8b82912db0cc86e81aa3106b21b19b93841e220f5b510a60190590d661a9a2398160826c88c4a885a9011a5105190b6128828485b318409f24fb6c0267609461ea1078cc3d98f8f8d251801a1988d97ea0100000a\n\n"3a1ea8d80ec2ea8b82912db0cc86e81aa3106b21b19b93841e220f5b510a60190590d661a9a2398160826c88c4a885a9011a5105190b6128828485b318409f24fb6c0267609461ea1078cc3d98f8f8d251801a1988d97ea0100000a\n\n
```

you can see that `\x01` is `01` then `\x03` is `03` then `!` is `21`. I want to take out all the non hex values in the second string.

1. What are chracters like ! and dP. Are they ASCII?
2. I can remove characters like new line like `hexString = hexString.Replace("\n", "");` But I'm not sure if that's the best way to do for all.
   3.Comparing the two strings, I see that `(`=`28` and `s@`=`7340` . Is there a table for conversion for this?

Comment: The second string has only hex values in it, which are digits from 0-9 a-f. `dP` is not  a character, it is two characters, which translated to hex are `6450`. `!` is a character. This seems like an XY problem - what are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: @NetMage I want to get remove all the non hex like ! and dp from the first string in the second line. I just want to keep stuff like \x01\x01\x03.

Comment: When you say "value in database", does the value in the database have literally the characters `\`, `x`, `0`, `1` in it - e.g. how long is that value? Also what about `\b` and `\t`?

Comment: I believe when the database(redis) is outputting the value to display it is adding stuff like `\b`, `\n`, and any other non hex stuff. That is why I want to get rid of it. This is a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/F4Xnr) from the database when I do the GET command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is given the quotes around the ouput that the database is displaying non-ASCII (Unicode?) characters as hex (e.g. `\x03`) and that the actual string contains a single character for each hex formatted display, in which case there is no difference to pick out - the character `d` is also the hex value `\x64`, it is just the database chooses to output visible characters as their normal letter - same thing with `\t` which could be output as `\x09` but they choose to use (C) standard control character abbreviations.

Found this:

> When it is displayed on screen, redis-cli escapes non-printable characters using the \xHH encoding format, where HH is hexadecimal notation.

In other words,

The cli is just using 3 different methods to display the values in the database field:

1. The character is printable, output the character (e.g. d, P, !, ").
2. The character is not printable, but has a C language standard escape sequence, output the escape sequence (e.g. \b, \t, \n).
3. The character is not printable and has no escape sequence, output the hex for the value of the character (e.g. \x03, \x01, \x00).

Comment: sorry, I still have trouble deciphering which characters is the actual value and which are outputed by redis-cli like "\n" and "!" which I believe is not stored in Redis. If I understand you correctly, I want to keep the non-ASCII so I just use regex to remove ASCII characters?

Comment: @dqv70219 You are wrong, all the characters displayed are stored in the database. See my update to my answer.